# Java interop - type inference failure with wildcard types

Tags: scala, lambda, type-inference

Is there any way to make this compile (without explicitly writing types)?

```
import java.util.{function => juf}

def jfun[A,B](f: A => B): juf.Function[A,B] =
  new juf.Function[A,B] { def apply(a: A): B = f(a) }

val l = new java.util.ArrayList[String]
l.stream.map(jfun(_.toInt))
```

Result:

```
error: no type parameters for method map: (x$1: java.util.function.Function[_ >: String, _ <: R])java.util.stream.Stream[R] exist so that it can be applied to arguments (java.util.function.Function[String,Int])
 --- because ---
argument expression's type is not compatible with formal parameter type;
 found   : java.util.function.Function[String,Int]
 required: java.util.function.Function[_ >: String, _ <: ?0R]
Note: String <: Any, but Java-defined trait Function is invariant in type T.
You may wish to investigate a wildcard type such as `_ <: Any`. (SLS 3.2.10)
                  l.stream.map(jfun(_.toInt))
                           ^
<console>:18: error: type mismatch;
 found   : java.util.function.Function[String,Int]
 required: java.util.function.Function[_ >: String, _ <: R]
                  l.stream.map(jfun(_.toInt))
                                   ^
```

Is there any better explanation to why this doesn't work than "scala simply can't do it"?

PS. I know about workarounds like adding extension `map` method on `Stream` - I nevertheless would like to hear some explanation for this type inference limitation.

Comment: I don' think you can. Scala just has very limited backwards inference (if any at all). One of the tradeoffs you face if you decide not to have global inference (which Scala doesn't).

Comment: Scala can't infer `R` from the existential parameter to `map`. You can call `stream.map[Int](...)`